# How do I return validation errors in JSON form from a form that submits remotely?

Tags: json, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, validationerror

I’m using Rails 4.2.3 and the “:remote => true” property to submit a form remotely.  However, I’m having trouble displaying the validation errors coming back.  In my controller I have

```
  def create
    @my_object = MyObject.new(my_object_params)
    @current_user = User.find(session["user_id"])
    @my_object.user = @current_user
    @date = Date.strptime(my_object_params[:day], "%m/%d/%Y")
    @my_object.day = @date
    respond_to do |format|
      if @my_object.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Saved successfully'
        format.html { redirect_to controller: "users", action: "index", notice: 'Saved successfully.' }
        format.js { render js: "window.location='/users'" }
      else
        format.html { render action: "index" }
        format.json { render json: @my_object.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js { render json: { error: @my_object.errors, success: false }, content_type: 'application/json' }
      end
    end
  end
```

And in my coffee script, I have

```
$(document).ready (data) ->
  $("#add_form").bind "ajax:error", (xhr, status, error) ->
    console.log(xhr) 
    console.log(status)
    console.log(error)
    render_form_errors(xhr, error)
    #Give an alert message
  $("#add_form").bind "ajax:before", (evt, data, status, xhr) ->
    hrs = $('#my_object_hour').val();
    min = $('#my_object_minute').val();
    sec = $('#my_object_second').val();
    $('#my_object_my_object_times_attributes_0_time_in_ms').val((hrs * 60 * 60 + min * 60 + sec) * 1000);
```

But none of the three fields, “xhr, status, error” contains the JSON errors.  The output of the console.log statements is

```
j…y.Event {type: "ajax:error", timeStamp: 1465418664628, jQuery112103593207809583596: true, isTrigger: 3, namespace: ""…}
users.self-a27ba2c….js?body=1:13 Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "ArgumentError in MyObjectsController#create↵↵invalid d…VER_PROTOCOL: "HTTP/1.1"↵↵Response headers↵None↵↵", status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error"}
users.self-a27ba2c….js?body=1:14 error
```

How do I transmit these back from my controller?

Thanks, -

**Edit:** In response to the answer, I edited my controller in the manner specified, and added this to my coffee script ...

```
$(document).ready (data) ->
  $("#add_form").bind "ajax:failure", (e, xhr, status, error) -> 
    console.log('error');
    console.log(e);
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(error);
    render_form_errors(xhr, error)  
  $("#add_form").bind "ajax:error", (xhr, status, error) ->
    console.log(xhr)
    console.log(status)
    console.log(error)
    render_form_errors(xhr, error) 
    #Give an alert message
  $("#add_form").bind "ajax:before", (evt, data, status, xhr) ->
    hrs = $('#my_object_hour').val();
    min = $('#my_object_minute').val();
    sec = $('#my_object_second').val();
    hrs_in_ms = hrs * 60 * 60 * 1000
    min_in_ms = min * 60 * 1000
    sec_in_ms = sec * 1000
    ms = hrs_in_ms + min_in_ms + sec_in_ms
    alert(ms)
    $('#my_object_my_object_times_attributes_0_time_in_ms').val(ms);
```

but upon submitting my form with errors, the none of the above gets called.  I know there are errors because I see (through debugging) the "else" clause of the "if @my_object.save" being called.

Comment: That's a 500 internal server error, due the `ArgumentError in MyObjectsController#create`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you will need to fix that 500 error, I have not taken your example but this is a rough example.

`bugs.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('hiii');
  $('#new_bug')

  .on('ajax:success', function(e, data, status, xhr) {
    console.log('success');
    console.log(e);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(xhr);
  })

  .on('ajax:error', function(e, xhr, status, error) {
    console.log('error');
    console.log(e);
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(error);
  })
})
```

in your controller, for e.g. my controller is 
`bugs_controller.js`

```
  def create
    @bug = Bug.new(bug_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @bug.save
        format.html { redirect_to @bug, notice: 'Bug was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @bug }
        format.js { render json: { success: true, bug: @bug.to_json }, content_type: 'application/json' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @bug.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js { render json: { error: @bug.errors, success: false }, content_type: 'application/json' }
      end
    end
  end
```

If you want `ajax:error` callback for your else block, you will need to provide with a different status code like 400, 500. For e.g.
`format.js { render json: { error: @bug.errors, success: false }, content_type: 'application/json', status: 500 }`, although I wouldn't really recommend this, as this is not the right way to do it. Your `ajax:success` will take care of validation errors, also since we are passing `success: false` we can check if there are validation errors in js.

Comment: Hi, I edited my quesiton to include your code (I use a coffee script where I think you have striaght up Javascript), but the "ajax:failure" method does not get called upon submission of my form with validation errors.

Comment: I forgot to include that block in the question, but I have edited it.  What event gets called when there are validation errors?  Is it ajax:failure?

Comment: You have not defined `ajax:success` that is why you are not seeing errors, here you will still define ajax:success even if there are validation errors, because there the request was valid and there are no server errors. ajax:error is called when there are 500, 400 responses.

Comment: @Dave were you able to get this to run

Comment: Yes I do see the function getitng invoked but I'm still having trouble getting the validation error messages to display on the client side.  There is still semething wrong with the above rendering those error messages properly but I haven't figured out what it is yet.